# force footer to bottom of page for short pages in my wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've got a website which I'm still playing with and editing however I'm a little lost with trying to make a footer stick to the bottom of the screen.

I tried ryanfait option (http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) but I cannot see how to make it work with my current theme.

I then tried a different method using absolute position etc but it placed the footer in the middle of the page on my long pages so clearly that wont work.

My current site is: http://goo.gl/PO3OYo and you can see on the front page what I mean about the footer not being right...

My site html is basically this:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="header"></div
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <div id="inner"></div>
    <div id="footer" class="footer"></div>
 </div>
```

and the CSS is

```
* { 
    margin: 0;
}

html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%;
}

body {
    background: #000000 url(images/bg.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    color: #444444;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 21px;
    height:100%;
}

#wrap {
    height:auto !important;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:100%;
    padding:0;
    position: relative; */ I tried this but it breaks long pages */
}

#inner {
    background: #FFF;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    padding: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#footer {
    background: #161616;
    color: #666666;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    padding: 20px, 0, 0, 0;
    clear: both; 
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid #222222;
    height: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute; */ I tried this but it breaks long pages */
}
```

Do you have any ideas how I can get it to work without the position: absolute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Come on dude, you were so close!

Make sure you follow the same structure:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
      <div id="header">fdsf</div>
        <div id="nav">ffd</div>
        <div id="inner">
          content here...
        </div>
        <div class="push"></div>            
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="footer">footer</div>
</body>
```

Then from ryan fait's

```
#wrap {
min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important; /* This line and the next line are not necessary unless you need IE6 support */
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

.footer, .push {
  height: 155px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

#footer {
  background: #161616;
  color: #666666;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  padding: 20px, 0, 0, 0;
  clear: both; 
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid #222222;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Example:
http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/YPymWV

I'd really advise having a muck about with my code in Codepen, just to get to grips with it. I sticky footer every footer I've ever made, and it **still** gets the better of me some times so just keep at it. There will also always be occasions when the above doesn't *quite* work...

Comment: I'd just noticed my footer shouldnt have been in the wrap!! Ugh rookie mistake lol... I've been looking at this for a while and the code is a nightmare.